# why a same webpage act differently in firefox and the IE8 browser?

Tags: html, css

Why does the same webpage act differently in firefox and the IE8 browser?

I am reading the source code of the website: http://www.conecrusherplant.net/products/crusher/pf-impact-crusher.html
I've noticed that if a put the mouse in the bottom,on the twitter logo, it will play well in
chrome or the firefox, but if I use IE8, it will not work so cool?

Why does act this way? Thanks.

Comment: Because IE is super. IE8 and less doesn't support CSS3, which is awesome.

Comment: Because IE is awesome

Comment: Welcome to the joys of browser compatibility!

Comment: There are *loads* of possible reasons why IE8 might act differently to Firefox. The obvious one is that it is IE8 was released in 2009 and doesn't have lots of modern browser features; what browser features are you using in this case? Another common reason is Quirks mode; have you checked the browser mode? You should explain the problem in more detail, explain what you've already done to try to solve it, and also provide the code that is going wrong in the question.

Comment: Because Firefox and Chrome supports CSS3 transition effects, but not IE8. But, IE10 and IE11 support CSS3 transition effects. That's why it is showing it differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because IE8 doesn't support transitions or transformations. But then again neither did Firefox 2.